# Vlookup using business day function

Tags: function, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to write a `vlookup` formula to pull the prior business day's Comments from Column "E" based on the Account # in Column "B".

If the Account # in Column B is present on both the prior and current business day's spreadsheets, then I need the `vlookup` formula to pull the prior business day's comment from Column E and place it in the respective cell for the current business day. If the account is new, then the cell in Column E needs to return blank.

I've tried to write it as follows, but it is not correct.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'[Unknown Accounts 02-16-15.xlsx]EV Accounts'!$B:$F,4,FALSE)
```

I was also told the `DIR()` function might work for this?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do what you want:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT("'[Unknown Accounts " & TEXT(TODAY()-1,"mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsx]EV Accounts'!$B:$F"),4,FALSE),"")
```

The sheet reference is today - 1 (ie yesterday) in the format you hinted at.

Then it uses indirect to convert it to a range from a text string

Finally it is wrapped in an `IFERROR` to return "" if it is an error (ie doesn't exist). **Caution**: using `IFERROR` will also return blank if there is a genuine error. You can break it down using other methods if you wish. Post back if you need help with that.